# What (if any) are the differences between Minolta's SAL500F8 and Sony's SAL500F80?

Tags: lens, sony, minolta

I would love to buy one of these autofocus 500mm f8 lenses, but information about these lenses is sparse, and I haven't been able to find anything at all about if Sony made any changes to the lens other than re-branding it.

I understand that the Sony lenses are likely to be in better shape as Sony did continue making them until almost 2008 (?), but I'm also interested in knowing if Sony changed components like the lens motor or material used in manufacturing for either better or worse?

Comment: Do you realize that what is Sony DSLR gear today might contain portions that emerged in Konica or Minolta factories?
http://www.engadget.com/2006/03/31/farewell-konica-minolta-hello-sony/

Comment: Yup, I know that. I think the SAL500F80 is just a rebranded Minolta lens, but I've not been able to find any information confirming / disproving this.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the detailed specifications and the results they produce they appear to be identical:
http://www.dyxum.com/lenses/Sony-AF-Reflex-500mm-F8_lens310.html
http://www.dyxum.com/lenses/Minolta-AF-Reflex-500mm-F8_lens25.html

The only way to be 100% sure would be to disassemble them side by side, but based on what information is available, them being the same is extremely likely.